# Python, Flask: Heroku can not open (and run) app

Tags: python, heroku, flask, cloud9-ide

I have a Flask app, written with the Cloud9 IDE. I run it locally with: "python manage.py runserver" in the Terminal.
This is then triggered:

```
manager.add_command('runserver', Server(
    use_debugger = True,
    use_reloader = True,
    host = os.getenv('IP', '0.0.0.0'),
    port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 5000))
    )
)
```

This piece of code is located in the manage.py file.

Now I want to run it with Heroku. I followed their tutorial entirely. I just didn't know what my Procfile should be. I wrote it like so:

```
web: gunicorn manage:runserver
```

Pushing the git etc. all seems to work fine. 
When I type: "heroku ps:scale web=1", I get this in my Terminal:

```
Scaling dynos... done, now running web at 1:Free.
```

When I type "Heroku open", I get this error:

```
Opening fierce-spire-3069... xprop:  unable to open display ''
 xprop:  unable to open display ''
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found
 xdg-open: no method available for opening 'https://fierce-spire-3069.herokuapp.com/'
 done
```

So, my app can't be opened..
When I open it with the Heroku site, I get an error message. This is what I've found in the logs:

```
2015-12-29T20:15:06.399443+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fierce-spire-3069.herokuapp.com request_id=c5d76e45-5d56-45f4-a2bc-75bd7fc08b7f fwd="81.82.128.183" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I changed my Profile to this:

```
web: python manage.py runserver "0.0.0.0:5000"
```

The above error message in the Heroku logs is gone, but there is a new one:

```
2015-12-29T21:30:37.938957+00:00 app[web.1]:     from tsb import app
2015-12-29T21:30:37.938955+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "manage.py", line 7, in <module>
2015-12-29T21:30:37.939002+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named tsb
```

This refers to this part of the manage.py code:

```
from tsb import app
```

"tsb" is the folder in which all of my project files are stored, it's the project folder. How come this couldn't be imported?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using gunicorn correctly. The [basic usage](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/run.html#gunicorn) is

```
$ gunicorn [OPTIONS] APP_MODULE
```

This is what you need to use in `Procfile`.

```
web: gunicorn [OPTIONS] APP_MODULE
```

I can't tell you what options to use. You can find that in [Heroku's gunicorn documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn). The important thing here is `APP_MODULE`.

It looks like your application instance is being exposed through `manage.py`, so you'd want to use

```
web: gunicorn manage
```

If you try this, however, it'll probably fail. By default gunicorn will look for something named `application` inside `APP_MODULE`. Your application seems to be named `manager`. That means you need

```
web: gunicorn manage:manager
```

Comment: I think I solved it without using gunicorn, but now I have a new error.. I edited my original question.

Comment: gunicorn wasn't your problem. Plus you shouldn't use the development server in production.